# Error 500 Internal Server Error - al hacer una petición Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

Este es mi código:

```
             $.ajax({

                url : "classes/MailManager2.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {accion: "rechazarConductor", conductorId : idconductor, labelmsg : msg, pendiente : pendiente,
                    c1 : $("#checkboxr1").is(':checked'), 
                    c2 : $("#checkboxr2").is(':checked'), 
                    c3 : $("#checkboxr3").is(':checked'), 
                    c4 : $("#checkboxr4").is(':checked'), 
                    c5 : $("#checkboxr5").is(':checked'), 
                    c6 : $("#checkboxr6").is(':checked'),
                    c7 : $("#checkboxr7").is(':checked'),
                    c8 : $("#checkboxr8").is(':checked'),
                    c9 : $("#checkboxr9").is(':checked'),
                    c10 : $("#checkboxr10").is(':checked'),
                    c11 : $("#checkboxr11").is(':checked'), 
                    c12 : $("#checkboxr12").is(':checked'), 
                    c13 : $("#checkboxr13").is(':checked'), 
                    c14 : $("#checkboxr14").is(':checked'), 
                    c15 : $("#checkboxr15").is(':checked'), 
                    c16 : $("#checkboxr16").is(':checked'),
                    c17 : $("#checkboxr17").is(':checked'),
                    c18 : $("#checkboxr18").is(':checked'),
                    c19 : $("#checkboxr19").is(':checked'),
                    c20 : $("#checkboxr20").is(':checked'), 
                    c21 : $("#checkboxr21").is(':checked'),
                    t1 : $("#name1").val()},                     
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!pendiente) { 
                        mostrarGrowl("<i class='fa fa-check fa-2x fa-fw fa-pull-left' style='vertical-align: middle'></i> Rechazar Conductor", "Se ha enviado una notificación al conductor");  
                    }
                    else {
                        mostrarGrowl("<i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-inverse fa-2x fa-fw fa-pull-left' style='vertical-align: middle'></i> Solicitud Pendiente", "Se ha enviado una notificación al conductor");
                    }

                    $("#dialogoRechazar").modal("hide");
                    unblock(); 

                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
```

En donde todos los datos que declaro en la variable data los quiero enviar a la clase de la url: MailManager2.php, pero me manda el error

Y este es codigo de MailManager2.php donde recibo los datos:

```
if(!$_POST["accion"]){
    $accion = $_GET["accion"];
}else{
    $accion = $_POST["accion"];
}
if ( $accion == "rechazarConductor" ) {
    $id = $_POST["conductorId"];
    $label = $_POST["labelmsg"];
    $pendiente = $_POST["pendiente"];
    $c1 = $_POST["c1"];
    $c2 = $_POST["c2"];
    $c3 = $_POST["c3"];
    $c4 = $_POST["c4"];
    $c5 = $_POST["c5"];
    $c6 = $_POST["c6"];        
    $c7 = $_POST["c7"];
    $c8 = $_POST["c8"];
    $c9 = $_POST["c9"];
    $c10 = $_POST["c10"];
    $c11 = $_POST["c11"];
    $c12 = $_POST["c12"];
    $c13 = $_POST["c13"];
    $c14 = $_POST["c14"];
    $c15 = $_POST["c15"];
    $c16 = $_POST["c16"];
    $c17 = $_POST["c17"];
    $c18 = $_POST["c18"];
    $c19 = $_POST["c19"];
    $c20 = $_POST["c20"];
    $c21 = $_POST["c21"];
    $t1 = $_POST["t1"];
```

Y si, la ubicación MailManager2.php si es correcta, eso se los aseguro.

Comment: Deberías revisar el log de php para tener más información.

Comment: Claramente no tiene que ver con la ubicación del archivo ni con nada del front. Tienes que debugguear el backend hasta ver cómo reproducir el error. A veces ayuda setear `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` para ver si logras que el error salga por pantalla y puedas verlo usando chrome devtools